# how to access admin controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to access admin controller from admin folder ,but I'm having some trouble getting this to work.

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
  Route::resource('ideas', 'AdminIdeaController');
});
```

AdminIdeaController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;
use DB;
use Route;
use User;
use Hash;
use Auth;
use Input;
use Logout;
use Validator;
use Authenticatable;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminIdeaController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {

        $data['idas'] = DB::table('ideas')
            ->get();


        return View('/admin/ideas.view',$data);
    }
}
```

folder path:

```
Http
    Controllers
        Admin
            AdminIdeaController .php
```

error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminIdeaController does not exist
```

i done everything according laravel:5.

Please help how can i route this folder file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your folder structure your namespace in route is mistake. It should be `Admin` not `admin` like this

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
  Route::resource('ideas', 'AdminIdeaController');
});
```

By this routes your controller should be inside the `Admin` folder and you can access this controller by `/admin/ideas` routes

You can make the controller inside folder by using command like this

```
php artisan make:controller foldername/controllername
```

If you want to create new folder and make the controller inside that folder you can use this command

```
php artisan make:controller foldername\\controllername
```

Comment: Thanks sixFingersMan, now its work, i'am  just change Admin into admin in prefix and now its working.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `AdminIdeaController`, but `Admin\AdminIdeaController` (note the `admin` subfolder). So, I think your route should be

```
Route::resource('ideas', 'Admin\AdminIdeaController');
```

Comment: Thanks Amarnasan ,but its not working , i already use this route.

Comment: @aniruddh this answer should be able to work except you are still using route group prefix

Comment: @Digitlimit without using group prefix ,still my routes not connect Admin/AdminIdeaController

Comment: Remove prefix and namespace then try once more. Or completely move it out of the route group

Comment: Can you state the url you're trying and failing?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the name of folder to namespace like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\name of folder
```

and then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If does not work try to make a new controller with command:

```
php artisan make:controller nameOfFolder/nameOfController
```